# C++ newbie: my loop should CHANGE a string, then print the string to a file. But it is ADDING to the string

Tags: c++, string, streaming, iostream

I have written C++ code for performing calculations.  There is a loop in the code.  At the end of each loop, I want to:

1) Get the time, a calculation result.

2) Make a name for a file. The name should contain the time.

3) Print the file name into an external file. Each new loop should overwrite the file name from the previous loop.

The first problem I had was that I could not delete the OLD file name.  So when my calculation was finished, the name was (for example):
calculationForRestartFile_0.0005476490.004925880.01763170.04375820

instead of:
calculationForRestartFile_04375820

I have updated this question to incorporate Mat's advice. Thanks Mat. But now I'm not getting anything in the external file.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  I would be very grateful for any advice.

```cxx
// Above loop:
  std::string  filename = "calculationForRestartFile_";  // Part of the file name that ALL files should have
  ofstream fileNameAtHighestTimeStream;    

  std::string       convertedToString;                  // This and the line below:
  std::stringstream storeNumberForConversion;           // For storing a loop number/time as a string

// Inside loop:
    storeNumberForConversion << global_time << flush;       // Turn the time/loop number into a string that can be added to the file name for a particular loop
    convertedToString = storeNumberForConversion.str();

    fileNameAtHighestTimeStream.open ("externalFile", ios::out | ios::app ); 
    fileNameAtHighestTimeStream << filename << convertedToString << endl;    // Append the time/loop name to the file name and write to the external file
    fileNameAtHighestTimeStream.close();

// End loop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that this line is adding to your `stringstream` inside the loop. You are never resetting its contents.

```
storeNumberForConversion << global_time << flush;
```

The simplest thing to do is to move the declaration of `storeNumberForConversion` inside your loop so it is created empty just before you use it.

Alternatively you could reset it after your formatting operation.

```
storeNumberForConversion.str( std::string() );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles! I implemented your first suggestion (moved declaration). Now the external file contains a list of names--one for each time.  Each name for each time is correct (yippee!).  I do still need to figure out how to get rid of the names for previous times (previous loops); for some reason, these are not being overwritten.

Comment: No need for an argument in the call to `str()`. I find it clearer without (looks a lot like a `reset()`-like function then.

Comment: P.S. I always thought that "re-declaring" (like I now do for storeNumberForConversion) would be bad.  Could you comment on this if you have time?  I mean, is it good style to re-declare?  I'm not complaining--I'm delighted it works--but I am curious.  Thanks!

Comment: @rubenvb: Clearer? But I _want_ to call the `.str` that takes a parameter; the one that doesn't take a parameter does something completely different.

Comment: @Ant: For clarity and readability, it's usually best to declare things with the smallest scope that is needed. In a loop context, it also means that you don't have to worry about any spurious old state that an object might be preserving which is exactly the issue that you came across. If there was a performance issue with creating or deleting an object repeatedly then it might be worth considering declaring and object outside of a loop when it might otherwise be able to be scoped inside the loop.

Comment: @Charles: Sorry, I thought wrong. I was confusing with the `str("")` form. That's the one I meant to be clearer and equivalent. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write the time to the file directly?

Comment: Hi Marty. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly here...  I need to write the name of a file to the external file--not just the time.  The external file name has to include "calculationForRestartFile_" and then the time.  It sounds weird, I know...  But it is required by some commercial/external code I'm using.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I meant trying something like `fileNameAtHighestTimeStream << filename << global_time << flush;` so you don't have to deal with the stringstreams.

Comment: Also to take a stab at your question in the comments of the other answer, re-declaring a variable just replaces the contents with the result of the default constructor.  I don't think there is a substantial difference between this approach and calling some erase method each iteration.